# how to access function in Json

Tags: javascript, json, object, properties, highcharts

I am able to access the onclick properties function for the printButton property at the end of the block. Although I am unable to initiate the onclick functions under the exportButton property.I have the following code.

```
B.exporting = {
    type : "image/png",
    url : "http://export.highcharts.com/",
    width : 800,
    enableImages : false,
    buttons : {
        exportButton : {
            symbol : "exportIcon",
            x : -10,
            symbolFill : "#A8BF77",
            hoverSymbolFill : "#768F3E",
            _titleKey : "exportButtonTitle",
            menuItems : [{
                textKey : "downloadPNG",
                onclick : function() {
                    this.exportChart()
                }
            }, {
                textKey : "downloadJPEG",
                **onclick : function() {
                    this.exportChart({
                        type : "image/jpeg"
                    })**
                }
            }, {
                textKey : "downloadPDF",
                onclick : function() {
                    this.exportChart({
                        type : "application/pdf"
                    })
                }
            }, {
                textKey : "downloadSVG",
                onclick : function() {

                    this.exportChart({
                        type : "image/svg+xml"
                    })
                }
            }
            }]
        },
         printButton : {
            symbol : "printIcon",
            x : -36,
            symbolFill : "#B5C9DF",
            hoverSymbolFill : "#779ABF",
            _titleKey : "printButtonTitle",

            onclick : function() {
                    this.print()
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I am binding keyboard controls to the click events using the jquery plugin this is what I used to print. This Works!:

```
Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+s', function(e) { B.exporting.buttons.printButton.onclick(this.print());
```

});

This code is what I tried to access an individual onclick function under the exportButton property in the json above

```
Mousetrap.bind('*', function(e) {B.exporting.buttons.exportButton.menuItems[0].onclick;});
```

The result i get is the value but i want to run the function as the onclick property does.Does anyone know how to run a function under a json property?I Appreciate any help here thanks folks.

Comment: You can't transmit functions in JSON, as far as I know.

Comment: This isn't JSON, it's a Javascript object literal. JSON is when you convert an object to a string so you can transmit it, save it in a file, etc.

Comment: I think your Ctrl-s binding is wrong -- you shouldn't call `this.print()` in the binding, it's done in the `onclick` function that you call.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mousetrap.bind('click', B.exporting.buttons.exportButton.menuItems[0].onclick);
```

Your ctrl-s binding also looks wrong, it should be:

```
Mousetrap.bind('ctrl+s', B.exporting.buttons.printButton.onclick);
```

The `printButton.onclick` function doesn't take an argument. Your binding calls `this.print` before calling the `printButton.onclick` function, and then the `printButton.onclick` function 
does it again.

Comment: Thank you for your corrections Barmar.  The printButton does work with your method.  Although the exportButton still does not get triggered with the binded keyboard control. In the objects property the function to download also passes a value for the type property. How do we trigger the function to respond the same way as the onclick is responding. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what framework you're using to bind the handlers. It doesn't look like jQuery, which is what I know, but I assumed that putting `click` there would work similar to jQuery.

Comment: I am using JQuery a plugin called mousetrap.js.  The component is dynamically drawn in svg and has a click event. I want to call the function with a keyboard control instead of a mouse click. When referencing the onclick in the exportButton I get an "object does not support this property or method". I know its because of the way we are referencing the function in the object, but need to know how to reference the function which sends the type:application/pdf as well to work.

Comment: In the handler functions, `this` is the target of the click event. If you want to call a jQuery or plugin method on it, you need to use `$(this).method()`.

Comment: so the object does reference the call with this, for example  onclick : function() {

                    this.exportChart({
                        type : "image/svg+xml"
                    })
I would like to know how to reference this event. In this case it is triggered with a mouse click. I would like to bind the keyboard event to the function.

Comment: If you want to reference the event, it should be `function(event) { ... }`.

Comment: So I see I am able to call the function but I just do not get the same  handling as the mouse click does from the onclick property in the object. I get an object doesn't support this property or method. So if I manually call the onclick i get an error, but if I click the item it works. I see that I must mimic what the function requires from the onclick. How would I send the same parameters to be handled   like clicking the mouse?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. I answered how to access the event in the handler. Are you asking how to _trigger_ the event?

Comment: Yes I would like to trigger the event. Is it possible in the onclick properties under the menuItems?